# iOS tableFooterView: Can't use UIButton?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios, ios4, tableview

I made a custom `UIViewController` with an `UIImageView` and a `UIButton` in it.  In the `tableView viewForFooterInSection` method I returned the view, and it displays correctly(i can see the button).  However, I can't touch the button.  It won't depress/highlight, and my connected IBAction doesn't fire.

Also, I have an object from the camera called takenPicture.  myImage is a `UIImageView` IBOutlet property of customView.  The imageView is always empty.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here is my code that is in the `viewForFooterInSection method`:

```
self.customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomView" bundle:nil];
customView.myImage.image = self.takenPicture;
return customView.view;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if the frame/bounds isn't set correctly for your view (the one containing the button and image view).  Likely it is defaulted with CGRectZero, and the reason you can see the button and image is because clipping is off.  But touch events wont filter up to the button if it is outside the bounds of its superview.

Comment: I created the view controller with Interface Builder, so I dragged and dropped the ImageView and UIButton.  I didn't programatically create it or do anything with the frame property